# Port absolutely refuses to open, despite best efforts

Tags: java, sockets, connection, port, portforwarding

So, I am trying to build a simple java chat application.

The application is supposed to establish a connection on port 5000. When I tried to give the jar to my girlfriend so she could test the client, she gets a connection refused, so I first though to check my ports. Port 5000 absolutely refuses to open.

I have tried everything I can think of (although I am definitely not IT savvy so I could've missed something);

Here are steps I have taken:

- In command prompt (while the server is running) I have used `netstat -an` and found port 5000 is listed as listening. When the server is not running, this port is not listed.
- I have disabled any and all antivirus software /firewalls on my rig, and in my router settings.
- I have set up a static IP for my rig.
- I have port forwarded port 5000 on my router and checked and double checked that I have done it correctly.
- I even contacted my ISP, who swears up and down that they don't block ports.
- I have tried other ports, not just 5000.

After the above steps, I have used *several different* sources to check whether port 5000 is open. *That thing is more blocked than Michael Moore's arteries.*

My question: ***Why does the internet hate me?***

EDIT: over endless hours of chat we (myself and user roelofs) were able to get it working on port 21, (the ftp port), which isn't a problem because there wont be any conflicts, but it isn't *right*. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd much appreciate it. It seems to be some kind of windows specific problem? Maybe? Can confirm ports are correctly forwarded and any kind of security *that I can think of* is off.

Comment: For a start, eliminate your code from the equation.  Just start listening with `netcat`, and then try telnetting to the port or something.  If you can't get that to work, this isn't a programming question, and should probably be redirected to http://superuser.com.

Comment: @redFIVE Did you even read the question?

Comment: yes, absolutely.  That's what it exists for.  If you're having connectivity issues, focus on proving connectivity exists before doing something more complex.

Comment: Is your router (if you have one) set up to forward the connection?

Comment: @roelofs I have a combined modem/router. And yes.

Comment: So when you say it's closed, you mean from anywhere outside your network?  Can you connect from another PC (not localhost)?  To which interface is the port bound?

Comment: @Oli If someone with enough rep votes to migrate the question that is fine with me; I am too new to be an accurate judge of what should go where.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the router line in your original question earlier...

Comment: @roelofs Yes, from anywhere outside my network. And I don't have another pc on the network to test from. And I'm gonna take a wild guess when you say interface and assume you mean TCP?

Comment: Have you tried other port ranges (ISPs have been known to lie ;) )?

Comment: Interface is eg Wireless LAN, Ethernet, Localhost, etc.  Normally it should be bound to all of them (ie, listens on all of them), but that can be something to look at.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans - if you want to take this to chat, I can try and troubleshoot with you before I go to bed.

Comment: You can also try and open a port/service on something known good (but using port 5000), like a SSH server or a web server or ftp server, and see if that works.  That should rule out anything on the ISP side, and bring it back to the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59288/discussion-between-hcbpshenanigans-and-roelofs).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that windows might have problems with listening sockets above 1024.  Running the code on a port lower than that (and setting up all port forwarding correctly) should get you to the point where you can debug.

Comment: Windows doesn't 'have a problem with ports over 1024'. I am presently using several hundred ports over 50,000 without any problems at all.

Comment: @EJP Go easy on him, he is a Linux user haha. And I think what he means is that port 21 (ftp) worked for some reason even though we did nothing else differently than we did for other ports (such as 5000, 22542, ect.)

Comment: We tested this for some hours, and it appeared to be a problem specific to his setup, hence the comment about being able to at least debug at the end.

Answer (score 1):

'Connection refused' means that there was nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. So, either the IP or port was incorrect or your server wasn't running. If the IP and port were correct it also means your firewall is forwarding the port correctly.

'Connect timeout' to a current Ip:port on the other hand indicates that your firewall isn't set up correctly.

Comment: I actually experienced both of those errors last night. (The latter first, made some code changes, and then the former)

Comment: also, through `netstats` I have determined that the server WAS listening